# How to use Multiple Checkboxes in ag-grid Angular 7

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am using Angular 7 and i want to use multiple checkboxes in my ag-grid that i want to select individually
Can someone help me on how to do this.
This thing i checked online but is not working for me

```
 {
        headerName: 'Auto Process Input',
        field: 'autoProcessInput',
        /*  editable: true, */
        cellRenderer: checkparams1 => {
            //  checkparams1.data.autoProcessInput=this.checkparams1;
            return `<input type="checkbox" [checked] = "checkparams1.data.autoProcessInput" (click)="checkBoxFn()" 
             [(ngModel)]="autoProcessInput==this.checkparams1"  />`;
        }
    },
    {
        headerName: 'isHoliday',
        field: 'isHoliday',
        /* editable: true, */
        cellRenderer: checkparams2 => {
            return `<input type="checkbox"  [checked] = "checkparams2.data.isHoliday" [(ngModel)]="checkparams2.data.isHoliday"  />`;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following column definition

```
{ 
    headerName: 'boolean', 
    field: 'boolean', 
    editable:true,
    cellRenderer: params => `<input type='checkbox' ${params.value ? 'checked' : ''} />`
}
```